Define Separate Security on Forwarder in SQL Server Distributed Availability Group
In short: Is it possible to define separate security specifically on the forwarder server in a SQL Server Distributed Availability Group, which crosses domains, in order to allow access to the forwarded database(s)?
Longer Explanation: For a myriad of reasons my team had settled on using a Distributed Availability Group to satisfy a need to make an existing multi-terabyte database (in an existing AG) available for another section of our company (in a separate domain), and we were under the impression we could define separate security on the forwarder environment to grant access to that domain’s accounts.
We have everything working so far, aside from this security question/issue. I have combed over as much of the documentation, blogs, and forums as I care to, but I have not been able to find anything referencing this either in the negative or affirmative.
I’m hoping there is some way to address this without having to find a way to add the other domain’s users to our main instance, mostly because we aren’t currently setup to support that from a domain standpoint and something like snapshot replication was/is off the table.

Would a one-way Forest trust be a possible solution here?

@RossBush, definitely something that’s in the works right now between our AD admins, but it’s not quite ready at this point. Not for this environment, but another one within our local domain, we’re testing out the one way forest trust and not having a whole lot of luck. I’m guessing there’s no real way to do this otherwise, though. The only possible way I could think of would likely be to fail over the Distributed AlwaysOn Group, add the groups to the other servers, and then fail back; however, given the size of this database, I don’t know if that is feasible.
